# OpenCV, Show Dynamic int 2D Array as Image (into Mat object)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I've got a problem as i explained at title. I want to assign 2D filled int ** (Dynamic) array to MAT object and then show it at screen. I've explained lots of questions, Google and got nothing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
**Here's my code which is not working.**

```
int** resultMatrix;
#define SIZE 800
//Some array process (Assign,Erosion etc..)
Mat A = Mat(SIZE, SIZE, CV_32S, &resultMatrix,2);  
    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", A );
```

This code block always showing a black screen. I also changed Size to 10 and printing matrix to screen as 1s and 0s, it's correct.(OpenCV version is 2.4.5)

Also i've got `wait(0)` code which is perfectly running at the end of this code.

Comment: Can you post more details about your initialization of `resultMatrix`?

Comment: it's initalizing with random 0s and 1s.

Comment: By "details" I mean the code in which you initialize `resultMatrix`.

Comment: Did you try imshow(..., 255000*A) ?? Pixel valued 1 dont differ much from pixel valued 0 I guess

Answer (score 0):

If Im not wrong I got similar problems in the past. Try to add a line `waitKey(1);` after `imshow( "Display window", A );` I guess it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry but everything is OK about code blocks. Its already there.

Comment: I see u use function `wait(0)` which is not in OpenCV Libs. The thing is, `imshow()` doesnt like external functions making delay, like `Sleep()`. Only `waitKey(1)` doesnt make such problem like black screen. At least I had such issue.

Comment: i tried both but didn't work. But i 've changed my matrix types to float which is static suddenly it started to work can't i use int** types in Mat constructor ?

Comment: U can use integers: signed/unsigned short int (16) and signed int (32). When u change your type for float and then it works, I guess u are using too small values of Int thats why your screen is black. Keep in mind that for example white colour in CV_32S is ~2^31. I can also guess that if u use unsigned char instead of float (and u chose type CV_8U), it will work as well. Nothing else coming my mind atm, sorry =/

Answer (score 0):

OpenCv doc says imshow divides values by 255 before displaying. You have to scale your data so that it isnt 0 after that division. Should be 255*255 for true white